# How can I get multicols to list across instead of down?

Tags: formatting, lists

**Preamble**

```
\usepackage{multicols}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \item Item 5
    \item Item 6
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

With the multicols package, the above gives two columns, but the way it will structure it is like so...

(a) Item 1 (d) Item 4

(b) Item 2 (e) Item 5

(c) Item 3 (f) Item 6

So it goes downwards, and then across to the next column

**Question:** Is there a way to modify this (or use an entirely different package/structure), so that the list goes across and then down instead, like so...

(a) Item 1 (b) Item 2

(c) Item 3 (d) Item 4

(e) Item 5 (f) Item 6

P.S. I am quite new to Latex so I apologise if this is a bit confusing

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tasks` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label = (\alph*)}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task item 1
  \task item 2
  \task item 3
  \task item 4
  \task item 5
  \task item 6
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]